# Connect to Google Cloud Datastore from Google Managed VM (Custom/Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-managed-vm, managed-vm

Is it possible to connect to Google Cloud Datastore from Google App Engine Custom Managed VM for Java? I believe it is possible from the Standard Managed VM, but is it possible from the Custom ones?

Comment: Those are two very different questions. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes#accessing_cloud_platform_services

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

## Standard Managed VMs

From [Using the Java Managed VM Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/):

> The Java runtime is available as a Managed VM standard runtime. A
>   standard runtime supports a subset of the App Engine service APIs.
>   Currently, Managed VMs support these services:
>
> - **Datastore**
> - Logging
> - Memcache
> - Search
> - Task Queue
> - URL Fetch
> - Users

## Managed VM with Custom Runtime

From [Building Custom Runtimes: Accessing Cloud Platform services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes#accessing_cloud_platform_services):

> Runtimes in Managed VMs can access any Google or third party services via standard APIs.

## Everything Else

You can also connect to Google Cloud Datastore from anywhere, using the [Datastore REST API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/overview).